# IIS Multiple FTP Sites

Tags: ftp, user-accounts, iis

I am in need of multiple FTP sites on the same server, to handle multiple application environments.

I have:

- Added IP address to Advanced TCP/IP Settings in control panel
- Added DNS entry to point at new IP
- Created FTP site (tried with host name and ip)
- Enabled  basic authentication at IIS and Site level
- Created a new local user
- User does NOT have to change password on next login
- Password never expires
- Account not locked
- Allow user authorization on FTP site
- Giver user permission on the physical location of the FTP site

When logging in to the FTP site I get `530 User cannot log in. Login failed.`.

This lead me to double, triple, and quadruple check the password. As a test I opened the command prompt and did a `runas /user:` using the new local user account and was successful.

I've tried everything I could think of and everything I could find. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you restart the `Microsoft FTP Service` in Windows services console on the server, after you'd made the changes?

Comment: I believe I did, but I tried again just to be sure. The issue persists.

Comment: what do your logs show? Also, do you users have NTFS access to the directories they're FTP'ing to?

Comment: Does IIS (IIS_IUSERS) have permission to access these folders? Are the folders inside `C:\inetpub\ftproot`?

Comment: My user does have NTFS access to the directory, however I'm not seeing anything being logged. I see the activity from the the original FTP site, but not my new one.

Comment: IIS_IUSRS didn't need permissions for the original, but giving IIS permissions to the directory made no difference. The folders are not inside `c:\inetpub\ftproot`, I have set the FTP physical path to another location. This is also how the original is setup, which works.